# Simple fullpage.js scrollOverflow issue

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

scrollOverflow plugin for fullpage.js does not work on jsfidde or my website.

Simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL9da6mz/) isolated reproduction.

Same code works using StackOverflow's code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fullpage").fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://www.victorwesterlund.se/src/lib/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.victorwesterlund.se/src/lib/fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.victorwesterlund.se/src/lib/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cotetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cotetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
      </h1>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cotetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
      </h1>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cotetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
      </h1>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cotetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: @AndyHolmes the section containing text that overflows the viewport does not scroll. Like I showed in the jsfidde example

Comment: I can scroll the window fine, so what's the desired output?

Comment: @AndyHolmes [this](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage) is the desired output. It does not scroll the last section with overflowing text. Tried on Chrome, Firefox and Edge. All latest versions

Comment: You have 2 sections in your jsFiddle, when I open that link and scroll the window the output on that window and the link you have just sent me is the exact same

Comment: @AndyHolmes wow that's odd. Could you check [my website](https://www.victorwesterlund.se/article) if you can scroll the last section there too

Comment: Yeah I can go from the waterfall to Lorem Ipsum //

Comment: @AndyHolmes Scrolling to section two is not the issue. scrollOverflow of the content inside section two is. The content inside section two exceedes the height of the viewport and should therefor be scrollable as a normal div with `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: ah okay I'm with you now, your question doesn't explain that very well. IT does appear to be cutting some text off but I can't see why - try reimplementing it and seeing if you accidentally missed something

Comment: @AndyHolmes My apologies, I just figured since I mentioned scrollOverflow as the issue in the title that would be enough. I'm sorry to say that reimplementing fullpage.js didn't solve the problem =/

Comment: Odd, sorry I can't be of any help at the minute. Though if it's any use, when I looked up the plugin the the overflow wasn't scrolling on the bigger section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to:

- Use the [latest scrolloverflow version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/dev/vendors/scrolloverflow.js) (0.0.5)
- Use [the latest fullPage.js version 2.9.6](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js)
- Use `scrollOverflow: true`

Your demo updated:
https://jsfiddle.net/yL9da6mz/3/

Comment: Thank you Alvaro, I solved it by redownloading and reimplementing fullPage with scrolloverflow